# How to redirect NGINX based on http cookie

Tags: http, nginx, server, routes

I have the NGINX config like this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #any request without the http cookie has to be redirected to login
    location / {
        if ($http_cookie ~* "user_tokens") {
            return 302 http://127.0.0.0:5000/;
            #break;
        } 
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

The idea is to configure the routes rule like

- Any request without the cookie will redirect to the login server(5000).
- Else it should serve the pages in the root.

But this is not working as expected, its always serving the pages from the root.

Comment: Use `!~*` for the condition where `$http_cookie` **does not** contain `user_tokens`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake to assume that `~*` is negative condition, it is actually `!~*`.

`if ($http_cookie !~* "user_tokens")`